# Generate Databricks personal access token using REST API

Tags: jwt, databricks, single-sign-on, aws-databricks, identity-provider

I'm exploring the use of the Databricks REST API to access data from underlying tables without relying on generating personal access tokens (PATs) through the web UI. Imagine I have Platform A, from which I obtain an "Authorization token," and I aim to use this token to authenticate in Databricks (Platform B). Both platforms are connected via the same identity provider (IDP) and employ single sign-on.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Can I authenticate in Databricks using the token obtained from Platform A and then generate a PAT using an API call?
2. Are there alternative methods to programmatically generate this token?

Despite consulting Databricks documentation, I couldn't find guidance on these aspects.
Most examples focus on generating personal access tokens through the web UI.

Additionally, when I attempted to use Postman to include the Authorization header with a JWT token, I encountered an error stating "unable to load OAuth config."

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: As regards the "unable to load OAuth config.", we will need more information about that. Do you have any application logs / error logs / http response status code / body ?